# Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, key

I am getting the following error : Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`

I have the following array called cities :

```
[
{ 'city' : `AIRDRIE`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `ALBERTA BEACH`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `ATHABASCA`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `BANFF`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `BARRHEAD`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `BEAUMONT`, 'province' : 'AB' }, 
{ 'city' : `BLACKFALDS`, 'province' : 'AB' },
... 
]
```

Now I want to filter the array :

```
const optionsCity = cities.filter(( {province} ) => {
  return province === this.state.province
})
```

which works fine until I try to open my dropdown.. I get error : Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`

My dropdown is react-dropdown, here is the code :

```
<Dropdown 
    options={optionsCity} 
    onChange={this.updateCity.bind(this)} 
    value={this.state.city} 
    placeholder="Select a City" />
```

Here is my updateCity

```
  updateCity(city) {
    this.setState({city: city.name})
  }
```

Anyone knows how to fix ?
I am sorry my English is very bad

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are mapping these options for the dropdown?

Comment: <Dropdown  options={optionsCity} onChange={this.updateCity.bind(this)} value={this.state.city} placeholder="Select a City" />

Comment: I fixed it, it seems like the array has to have the variables 'value' and 'label'. My bad !! Thank you still !

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown, if you are using an object array of options, you need it to be in a particular format with keys - 'value' and 'label'

```
{ value: 'one', label: 'One' }
```

The filter returns an array of objects and not just an array of city names.
You will need to create a new objects array with the above keys or just use a flat array of city names